# Route through a proxy server in laravel

Tags: laravel, http-proxy

I am using Laravel and I am attempting to make an https request (this works on localhost) but now I am putting on a server. I have been advised that I will need to setup configuration to route through a proxy server. I have been provided with a URL and Port.

Apparently these need setting up for any part of the system that attempts to connect externally. I was advised that there may be a config file for variables/constants, thought the person that provided me this information could not say what variables need to be set in Laravel.

I believe I may need to add to the routes/api.php having read the [laravel guide for routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-namespaces) but this is not clear to me. For example it says:

> Available Router Methods
>
> The router allows you to register routes that
>   respond to any HTTP verb:
>
> `Route::get($uri, $callback);`

But it is not clear to me what I am putting there. Could it be the request to dev.tescolabs or the url and port information?

I have done web routes before eg. `Route::get('/list', 'IngredientsController@display');` but this extra step is confusing.

My code which works locally is:

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
$request = new Http_Request2('https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/');
$url = $request->getUrl();
$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'key',
);
$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(

//        Request parameters

//    'tpnb' => '{string}',
//    'tpnc' => '{string}',
//    'catid' => '{string}',
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    $result = $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the line:`$url = $request->getUrl();` I added the below:

```
$request->setConfig(array(
        'proxy_host' => 'wwwproxy.address',
        'proxy_port' => port number

));
```